# OSM Geocoding fails

Tags: wordpress, geocoding

CiviCRM rookie, and having problems with the Geocoder.

I'm using Wordpress 5.3.2 multisite and CiviCRM 5.23 and I've installed the OpenStreetMap Geocoding extension 1.2.1

In Administer/System Settings/Mapping and Geocoding Providers I have Mapping provider set to OpenStreetMaps and OpenStreetMapCoding as the Geocoding Provider.  No key (I think I'm right in assuming this isn't needed?).

I have Street Address Parsing set as on in Administer/Locationisation/Address Settings

In Administer/Systems Settings/Scheduled Jobs I have geocoding=1 set as the parameter in Geocode and Parse Addresses.

If I execute now, then the response I get in the log is:

```
    Finished execution of Geocode and Parse Addresses with result: Success (Addresses Evaluated:
    1 Addresses Geocoded: 0 Street Addresses Parsed: 0 
    Following is the list of contacts whose address is not parsed: Contact ID: 1 xxxxx (...)
```

I'd wanted it to geocode the 100 contacts I had imported.  It seems to have read the one organisation record I have and failed to geocode that.

If I add or edit an existing address in the contacts screen it does appear to geocode that.

Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: Do the addresses have a country? If it's missing that will stop geocoding.

Answer (score 3):

It's come up before that street address parsing only works for US addresses. Try just going with geocoding.